# How to execute custom action only when previous version of product is not installed?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I have a custom action that has to execute only when older version of this product is not installed.
What conditions I have to use to execute the CA only when older version of product is not installed otherwise the CA has to skip .
 I had tried with the condition "Not ProductVersion" but it didnt works for me.
ProductVersion is registry key with  product installed version value.

Comment: Please, share your wix code

Comment: I think you'd probably have to use the Upgrade table, setting the msidbUpgradeAttributesOnlyDetect attribute, and using the 'ActionProperty' as part of the condition for your Custom Action: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/upgrade-table